# Python syntax error in a while block

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop

I get a syntax error in the following code:

```
if value[0] == "ta" or "su":
        num_var = len(value)
        i = 0
        while value[i][0] != "-" and i <= num_var:
            if i == 0 and value[0][0].isdigit(): 
                f3["var_%s" %i] = VARFD[[value[0].split("/")[1]]
            else: 
                f3["var_%s" %i] = VARFD[[value[0]]
            f4["val_%s" %i] = "T"
            i += 1
```

it claims that the syntax error is on line that starts with "else:". What's wrong with it?

Comment: you know that `value[0] == "ta" or "su"` is not the same as `value[0] == "ta" or value[0] == "su"`, right?

Comment: `value[0] in ('ta', 'su')` would be even nicer. And please do not inline if bodies. It's ugly to read, especially for longer lines.

Comment: this is actually a very non-readable code: bad indentation, too much inlines and more than 80 chars per line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your supply of new lines limited or why are you writing code like this?

Your error is here, one `]` is missing:

```
VARFD[[value[0].split("/")[1]]
```

Comment: if i add new lines, won't the program be slower?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a square bracket in the

```
        if i == 0 and value[0][0].isdigit(): f3["var_%s" %i] = VARFD[[value[0].split("/")[1]]
```

line.  But Python code really isn't meant to be this densely written.  Space and light!

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as that you're missing an end bracket on the line before the else.

```
VARFD[[value[0].split("/")[1]]
```

I suspect the expression should be

```
VARFD[value[0].split("/")[1]]
```

It's pretty much sure sign that you should break apart and simplify your code when errors like this show up :)